Micronaut 4: validation not working, DTO not getting validated
I have setup validation in Micronaut 4.6.1 and it's not working for me. The DTO doesn't get validated. The request passes through to the controller as if the validation annotations don't exits.
DTO (validation that the properties are not null):
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Introspected
public class TripCreateRequest {

    @NotNull
    private LocationDto start;

    @NotNull
    private LocationDto destination;
}

Controller (create endpoint):
 @Post
    TripCreateResponse createOne(@Body @Valid TripCreateRequest tripCreateRequest) {
        Trip trip = new Trip(
                new Location(tripCreateRequest.getStart().getLatitude(), tripCreateRequest.getStart().getLongitude()),
                new Location(tripCreateRequest.getDestination().getLatitude(), tripCreateRequest.getDestination().getLongitude())
        );

        trip = this.tripService.createOne(trip);
        return TripCreateResponse.from(trip);
    }

dependencies (I am using Jackson along with validation):
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

build (the annotation processors):
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <!-- Uncomment to enable incremental compilation -->
          <!-- <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation> -->
          <annotationProcessorPaths combine.children="append">
            <path>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
              <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-http-validation</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.core.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut.validation</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-validation-processor</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.validation.version}</version>
              <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                  <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                  <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
              </exclusions>
            </path>
          </annotationProcessorPaths>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.group=com.example</arg>
            <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.module=demo-m2</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

What am I doing wrong? The code acts as if the validation annotations don't exist.
Trying Serde instead of Jackson didn't work for me either.
